# Spurious unblocking in boost thread

Tags: multithreading, boost, wait, conditional-statements

I came across this interesting paragraph in the [Boost thread documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.condvar_ref) today:

```
void wait(boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex>& lock)
```

...

> Effects: Atomically call lock.unlock()
>   and blocks the current thread. The
>   thread will unblock when notified by a
>   call to this->notify_one() or
>   this->notify_all(), or **spuriously**.
>   When the thread is unblocked (for
>   whatever reason), the lock is
>   reacquired by invoking lock.lock()
>   before the call to wait returns. The
>   lock is also reacquired by invoking
>   lock.lock() if the function exits with
>   an exception.

So what I am interested in is the meaning of the word "spuriously". Why would the thread be unblocked for spurious reasons? What can be done to resolve this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[This article by Anthony Williams](http://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/threading/condition-variable-spurious-wakes.html) is particularly detailed.

> Spurious wakes cannot be predicted:
>   they are essentially random from the
>   user's point of view. However, they
>   commonly occur when the thread library
>   cannot reliably ensure that a waiting
>   thread will not miss a notification.
>   Since a missed notification would
>   render the condition variable useless,
>   the thread library wakes the thread
>   from its wait rather than take the
>   risk.

He also points out that you shouldn't use the `timed_wait` overloads that take a duration, and you should generally use the versions that take a predicate

> That's the beginner's bug, and one
>   that's easily overcome with a simple
>   rule: always check your predicate in a
>   loop when waiting with a condition
>   variable. The more insidious bug comes
>   from timed_wait().

[This article by Vladimir Prus](http://vladimir_prus.blogspot.com/2005/07/spurious-wakeups.html) is also interesting.

> But why do we need the while loop,
>   can't we write:

```
if (!something_happened)
  c.wait(m);
```

> We can't. And the killer reason is that 'wait' can
>   return without any 'notify' call.
>   That's called spurious wakeup and is
>   explicitly allowed by POSIX.
>   Essentially, return from 'wait' only
>   indicates that the shared data might
>   have changed, so that data must be
>   evaluated again.
>
> Okay, so why this is not fixed yet?
>   The first reason is that nobody wants
>   to fix it. Wrapping call to 'wait' in
>   a loop is very desired for several
>   other reasons. But those reasons
>   require explanation, while spurious
>   wakeup is a hammer that can be applied
>   to any first year student without
>   fail.

Comment: Looks like we've been finding the same pages, which isn't entirely unexpected :)

Comment: yeah this is kind of a summary of my research today when I figured out the cause of the horrible bug that I was suffering from. The boost documentation could be clearer on this point

Comment: I've found boosts entire system for waiting and notifying—especially in boost::interprocess—is very frustrating. I would only use it if you need it to be cross-platform and done now.

Answer (score 2):

[This blog post](http://vladimir_prus.blogspot.com/2005/07/spurious-wakeups.html) gives a reason for Linux, in terms of the `futex` system call returning when a signal is delivered to a process. Unfortunately it doesn't explain anything else (and indeed is asking for more information).

The [Wikipedia entry on spurious wakeups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spurious_wakeup) (which appear to be a posix-wide concept, btw, not limited to boost) may interest you too.

Comment: Hmm yeah that isn't really a satisfying answer given that it only really applies to one platform, although I guess if it really is incredibly difficult to get it to work "correctly" on Linux, then that could be a valid reason to document spurious wakeups