# Is there a problem with this usage of boost condition code?

Tags: c++, boost, synchronization, conditional-statements

Will this code ever wait on the mutex inside the producer's `void push(data)`?

If so how do I get around that?

```
boost::mutex access;
boost::condition cond;

// consumer
data read()
{
  boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(access);

  // this blocks until the data is ready
  cond.wait(lock);

  // queue is ready
  return data_from_queue();
}

// producer
void push(data)
{
  //<--- will a block ever happen here?
  boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(access);
  // add data to queue

  cond.notify_one();  
}
```

Let's say I have a thread pool for(;;) loop and I have read() being called from a thread in this pool.  Then I process data on it.  And I call push() with some external thread.   My question is, can that external thread ever block on its call to push(data)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When .wait() is called it will block the calling thread in your thread pool and release the mutex.  It will return when someone calls notify_one() or notify_all().  Before the thread that was blocked returns though, it will re-acquire the mutex and unblock the thread in your thread pool.

So the call to `void push(data)` by your external thread will only block temporarily up until .wait() is called.

See the [boost documentation on the condition's wait function](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_34_0/doc/html/boost/condition.html).

Comment: This is not true. void push(data) will not block until a wait is called. It will only block if it cannot aquire the mutex, and have to wait until someone else releases the mutex.

As a side note the data read() function MUST check wether there are actually items in the queue (maybe an item was added while it was not calling wait(), or a spurious wakeup occured). The function HAVE to do "while(queue is empty) cond.wait(lock); return data_from_queue();"

Answer (score 8):

`wait` can return without `notify` ever being called. This is called a [spurious wakeup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625340/spurious-unblocking-in-boost-thread). To handle this, code using a condition should always have a loop around the `wait` that checks that the expected condition really is in effect. For example:

```
queue data_queue;
boost::mutex access;
boost::condition cond;

// consumer
data read()
{
  boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(access);

  while (queue.is_empty()) {
    // this blocks until the data is ready
    cond.wait(lock);
  }

  // queue is ready
  return data_from_queue();
}

// producer
void push(data)
{
  boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(access);

  // add data to queue
  queue.push_back(data);

  cond.notify_one();  
}
```

Conceptually, "condition" is kind of misleading. Instead you can think of it as a signal. You are signalling another thread or threads to wake up, but you are not promising anything. Just, "Hey, maybe there's some data ready, why don't you go check eh?"

Comment: Let's say I have a thread pool for(;;) loop and I have read() being called from a thread in this pool.  Then I process data on it.  And I call push() with some external thread.   My question is, can that external thread ever block on its call to push(data)?

Comment: Assume for example that the queue is empty()

Comment: As exampled in the other answer, .wait call releases the mutex, allowing 'push' to acquire it.